# An equivalent to “powered by” in software

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, informatique

How can I say “powered by” in French in a software context.

Example English phrases: *Powered by Microsoft*, *Powered by Linux*, *Powered by StackExchange*.

I've “tasted” *alimenter*, *fournir*, *produire* but none of them sounds quite right…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wordpress' translation use « *propulsé* ». Which is not bad,  albeit a it odd. If I were to say this in French, I would probably go for a word that reflect what *powered* is in this particular case

- ***Réalisé** avec MS Office*
- ***Soutenu** par StackExchange*
- ***Conçu** sous Linux*
- ***Écrit** avec vim*
- …

Comment: Euh, *soutenu* ? bof.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je pensais à CareerOverflow.

Comment: Ouais mais le sens est complètement différent de « powered by ».

Answer (score 1):

Dans son blog, [Journal d'un avocat](http://www.maitre-eolas.fr/), Eolas utilise le registre qui lui est familier (c'est moi qui graisse):

> Mes logiciels, comme mes clients, sont libres. Ce blog est **délibéré**
>   sous Firefox et **promulgué** par Dotclear.

Et tout au fond, en bas à droite, il est mentionné, en traduction plus littérale:

> **Propulsé** par Dotclear